Example of nonnuclear Montel space
It is well known that if a nuclear space is quasicomplete and barreled, it is Montel.
I also know that some complete Montel spaces exist that are not nuclear, though my proof is rather convoluted, which leads me to my question: is there a simple (in some sense) example of a Montel space which is not nuclear?

For Köthe sequence spaces $\lambda^p(A)$, i.e., countable intersections of weighted sequence spaces
$$\ell^p(a_n)=\{(x_k)_k\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}: (a_n(k)x_k)_k\in\ell^p\},$$ all relevant topological properties can be characterized in terms of the weights, see, e.g., the book Introduction to Functional Analysis by Meise and Vogt.
The characterization of the Montel property is rather involved but it not too difficult to prove that $\lambda^p(A)$ is Schwartz (which is stronger than Montel) or nuclear, respectively, if and only if, for each $n\in \mathbb N$ there is $m\ge n$ such that $a_n/a_m\to 0$ or, respectively, $a_n/a_m\in\ell^1$. It is then easy to come up with Köthe spaces which are Schwartz but not nuclear.
